# How to link to another FIORI app using annotations?

Tags: templates, annotations, sapui5

I tried to link my app to another app. 
I was able to link it to Sample app using following code:

```
    <Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataFieldForIntentBasedNavigation">
        <PropertyValue Property="SemanticObject" String="Action"/>
        <PropertyValue Property="Action" String="toappnavsample2"/>
        <PropertyValue Property="Label" String="SO Navigation (M)"/>
        <Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.Importance" EnumMember="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.ImportanceType/Medium"/>
    </Record>
```

I don't know what to write for linking my own app "SelfDemo". 
I think I'm not able to find the semantic object for my app "SelfDemo". 
Please let me know if i'm on right track.

Answer (score 0):

The cross app navigation functionality is provided by a Fiori launchpad service. Therefore, the information which application is mapped to a certain intent (=combination of SemanticObject and Action) has to be given in the Launchpad configuration. In other words, you need to use the combination of SemanticObject and Action that was defined for your app in the Launchpad configuration.

If you're using the ABAP launchpad, information can be found here:
[Configuring Navigation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/bd/8ae3d327ab4541bcce8e7353c046fc/content.htm?frameset=/en/bd/8ae3d327ab4541bcce8e7353c046fc/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/bd/e12a271f0647e799b338574cda0808/plain.htm&node_id=83&show_children=true#jump83)

If you're using the cloud launchpad, information can be found here:
[About the SAP Fiori Launchpad Configuration Cockpit](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/cloud_portal_flp/frameset.htm?6e10f92fc7e04a92a85ba482f95d2b36.html)